# session.connect java.net.sockettimeoutexception when deploying an application on remote server using netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ftp, remote-access, remote-server

I am trying to deploy a php application on remote server using NetBeans so i can transfer scripts directly but i'm having this exception:

> cannot connect to server ftp.*************.net
>
> (cause: session.connect java.net.socketTimeoutException Read timed
>   out).

Why?
Any solutions?

Comment: Wrong URL? Wrong password? Firewall issue? Netbeans configuration error? Any of a dozen other reasons? There's not really enough here to help. Can you connect with a different FTP client?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is insufficient information to diagnose the problem